# Python DictWriter printing blank row and header when merging two CSVs

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to take certain rows from my input CSV and append them to my output CSV. The code does grab rows that contain the word "Page" in the "Row" column, but it also prints the headers and a blank row between each row.

Can anyone tell me how to not append the header and blank rows? Thank you.

```
import csv
with open('Input.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f, open('Output.csv', '+a', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()  # For writing header
    for row in reader:
        if row['Row'] == 'Page':
            writer.writerow(row)
```

EDIT:
My code looks like this now as I think is suggested but I still receive the original issue of the header being copied and a blank row between each line from the input.csv.

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f, open('output.csv', '+a', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()  # For writing header
    for row in reader:
        if row['Row'] == 'Page':
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I tried this out with a csv file I had, and it also printed a blank line between rows. (It only printed the header once, at the top of the file). I also changed `+a` to just `a` and that didn't help.

Comment: It's going to be easier to help you if you post an example row, and an example of the "wrong" output. You code works fine with a properly formatted CSV.

Comment: I would upload my file but I do not see an option to attach it to my post. The file appears to be formatted fine but I agree that it could be the issue.

Comment: just add a small portion, like Chris Charley did

Comment: Python 3.7.6

I updated my code with Chris Charley's recommendation but the output still has the header and a blank row between each appended line.

Comment: You added the `newline=''` to the input file *instead of* the `open` for the output file. Make that change to see if you get your desired results.

Comment: Please remove the results file and run the code only once. Do you still have the problem?

Comment: I need the output.csv file. The object is to copy the rows from the input file that matches the script criteria and append them to the output.csv file.

Comment: Change the to see if you get the result. `with open('input.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f, open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f_out:`

Comment: That gets me closer. It overwrote the output.csv file with the data from the input.csv that matched the criteria along with the header. I am trying to append that data to my output.csv file which already exist before running the script and contains data.

EDIT: I changed the last 'w' to +a and it appends the data, but only after printing the header row from the input.csv.

Comment: It is not clear why you are appending to a file with existing results. You should consider simply filtering the CSV results to a temporary file, and then only merge those to the existing file.

Comment: I didn't think it through well `:(`  If you are appending to an existing file, then you do need the append mode,. And you probably don't want to write the header again since it is in the appended file already (`writer.writeheader()`)

Comment: It works perfect now. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code from the docs:

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

You can see that `newline=''` is an argument to open for the write/append file. With this argument, there were no blank lines between the rows when I wrote to the output file from my sample input csv file.

A snippet of the csv file I read:

```
brewery_id,brewery_name,review_time,review_overall,review_aroma,review_appearance,review_profilename,beer_style,review_palate,review_taste,beer_name,beer_abv,beer_beerid
10325,Vecchio Birraio,1234817823,1.5,2,2.5,stcules,Hefeweizen,1.5,1.5,Sausa Weizen,5,47986
10325,Vecchio Birraio,1235915097,3,2.5,3,stcules,English Strong Ale,3,3,Red Moon,6.2,48213
10325,Vecchio Birraio,1235916604,3,2.5,3,stcules,Foreign / Export Stout,3,3,Black Horse Black Beer,6.5,48215
10325,Vecchio Birraio,1234725145,3,3,3.5,stcules,German Pilsener,2.5,3,Sausa Pils,5,47969
1075,Caldera Brewing Company,1293735206,4,4.5,4,johnmichaelsen,American Double / Imperial IPA,4,4.5,Cauldron DIPA,7.7,64883
1075,Caldera Brewing Company,1325524659,3,3.5,3.5,oline73,Herbed / Spiced Beer,3,3.5,Caldera Ginger Beer,4.7,52159
1075,Caldera Brewing Company,1318991115,3.5,3.5,3.5,Reidrover,Herbed / Spiced Beer,4,4,Caldera Ginger Beer,4.7,52159
1075,Caldera Brewing Company,1306276018,3,2.5,3.5,alpinebryant,Herbed / Spiced Beer,2,3.5,Caldera Ginger Beer,4.7,52159
1075,Caldera Brewing Company,1290454503,4,3,3.5,LordAdmNelson,Herbed / Spiced Beer,3.5,4,Caldera Ginger Beer,4.7,52159
```

Here is the code I used for the 'beer' csv file to get the results without the extra newlines:

```
import csv
with open('beer.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f, open('AAA.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f_out:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()  # For writing header
    for row in reader:
        if row['brewery_id'] == '10325':
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the CSV you had that created the problem the OP had?

Comment: Sorry. I do not know how to quote code in a reply. I updated my original post with an edit.

Comment: I can't reproduce the original issue with your beer file.

Comment: @oz123 The issue occurs when the output file is opened without the `newline=''` argument to the `open(...`

Comment: I did use the original snippet and the code works fine, without the keyword newline.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to the results file every time you try and run then code.
In the original code you are opening the CSV writer in `+a` append mode.

Full accounting with IPython session:

```
In [44]: import csv
    ...: with open('OCR.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f, open('OCRresults.csv', '+a', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    ...:     writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    ...:     writer.writeheader()  # For writing header
    ...:     for row in reader:
    ...:         if row['Row'] == 'Page':
    ...:             writer.writerow(row)
    ...: 

In [45]: cat OCRresults.csv
Name,Size,Row
Foo,32,Page
Naz,33,Page

In [46]: import csv
    ...: with open('OCR.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f, open('OCRresults.csv', '+a', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    ...:     writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    ...:     writer.writeheader()  # For writing header
    ...:     for row in reader:
    ...:         if row['Row'] == 'Page':
    ...:             writer.writerow(row)
    ...: 

In [47]: cat OCRresults.csv
Name,Size,Row
Foo,32,Page
Naz,33,Page
Name,Size,Row
Foo,32,Page
Naz,33,Page
```

Clear the file with wrong results (actually redundant because of `w` mode).

```
In [48]: rm OCRresults.csv
```

And now notice how I open then file with `w` mode:

```
In [49]: import csv
    ...: with open('OCR.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f, open('OCRresults.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    ...:     writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    ...:     writer.writeheader()  # For writing header
    ...:     for row in reader:
    ...:         if row['Row'] == 'Page':
    ...:             writer.writerow(row)
    ...: 

In [50]: cat OCRresults.csv
Name,Size,Row
Foo,32,Page
Naz,33,Page

In [51]: import csv
    ...: with open('OCR.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f, open('OCRresults.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    ...:     reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    ...:     writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    ...:     writer.writeheader()  # For writing header
    ...:     for row in reader:
    ...:         if row['Row'] == 'Page':
    ...:             writer.writerow(row)
    ...: 

In [52]: cat OCRresults.csv
Name,Size,Row
Foo,32,Page
Naz,33,Page
```

Note that, I truncated the output file by opening it with `w` mode.

Comment: No. I have a Input.csv and output.csv backedup. The input file has 100 rows, with 10 having the word "Page" in the "Row" column. When I run the script 10 rows that meet the "Page" criteria are copied to the output.csv, but with the input.csv header and a blank row between each of the 11 lines.

Comment: The issue is that you are using 'append' mode.

Comment: Is there another mode I should use?

Comment: See my answer ...  when you open a file after processing, you probably want to use `w` mode.

Comment: I am sorry I have no idea what you mean. I changed to a "w" and it just caused the original data in the output.csv to be deleted. The input.csv data is there but with blank rows.

I want to keep the data that is in the output.csv and append the data from the input.csv that matches the scripts criteria.

Comment: You got to reduce your problem to the minimum. Why is your output data already containing data? Are you writing multiple times to the same output from different functions? Do you have the problem when you run just the code snippet or as part of a larger program?

Comment: What? Why does my output data already contain data... because that's how this works. Why is the sky blue? Why is money green? Why is water wet? I want to take certain rows from one csv and append them to another.

Comment: Again, are you running *just* the snippet of code you posted?